GeoNetwork : Make the entry of values ​mandatory
We have a data catalog based on GeoNetwork. Due to their optional entry, we suspect that some fields (e.g. theme, geography) of some records have no value entered. In order to overcome this problem for future records (which directly impacts the result/reliability of the metadata search), is it possible to make the entry of certain fields mandatory? While keeping the record model that we currently use (which is for information: the ISO standard Geographic information -- Metadata (iso19115-3.2018)).
